# i have a error in exporting database from phpmyadmin Environment

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, xampp

I created a database in a localhost/PHPMyAdmin environment with 5 tables. Using XAMPP. But after exporting it and re-importing it, my codes are not displayed correctly and the following code is displayed instead. I open my database to XAMPP and SQL server management. But both times the result was the same. Can anyone help me?

I di this steps to export:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778403/import-export-very-large-mysql-database-in-phpmyadmin/14984816



<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><h1>Error</h1><p><strong>SQL query:</strong>  <a href="#" class="copyQueryBtn" data-text="SET time_zone = &quot;+00:00&quot;">Copy</a>
<a href="index.php?route=/database/sql&sql_query=SET+time_zone+%3D+%22%2B00%3A00%22&show_query=1&db=librarydb"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit">&nbsp;Edit</span></a>    </p>
<p>
<code class="sql"><pre>
SET time_zone = &quot;+00:00&quot;
</pre></code>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>MySQL said: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F8.0%2Fen%2Fserver-error-reference.html" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help"></a>
</p>
<code>#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: '+00:00'</code><br></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting database - unknown or incorrect time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382767/exporting-database-unknown-or-incorrect-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I reset my phpadmin setting, worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this problem by reset your mysql setting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).